# Add image with text in header of every page in pdf file using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

When we use below code it add only one image. Is any other option to add image & text on every page?

private void AddHeader(string filephysicalpath, string nfile)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filephysicalpath);
            String path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Documentheader"].ToString() + Session["headerImg"];
            Stream inputImageStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

```
        Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {
                int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {
                    string footer = Convert.ToString(Session["Footer"]);
                    if (Session["Footer"] != null)
                    {
                        // Phrase ft = new Phrase(footer, blackFont);
                        float marginLR = 36;
                        float marginB = 2;
                        float footerHeight = 10;
                        Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetCropBox(i);
                        if (pagesize == null)
                        {
                            pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(i);
                        }
                        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                                pagesize.Left + marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB,
                                pagesize.Right - marginLR, pagesize.Top + marginB + footerHeight
                            );



                        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
                        image.SetAbsolutePosition(rect.Left, rect.Top - image.ScaledHeight);
                        var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
                        pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
                        inputImageStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        // ct.AddElement(new PdfPTableHeader (image));

                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filephysicalpath, bytes);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you do

```
       var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
       pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
```

I.e. you always use the `OverContent` of page 1 and add the image to it. Instead you should use the `OverContent` of page `i`:

```
       var pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
       pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
```

Furthermore, you should import the image only once, i.e. move the line

```
     iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
```

above the loop.

Comment: i want to change height & Width of header image. is there any solution for that

Comment: Yes, there are a number of methods in the iText `Image` class which allow scaling by some factor or to fit in some target dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set inputImageStream to beggining before next use?

```
inputImageStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Meybe its pointer is on the end of stream and next call return empty image?

Comment: still i add header only in first page ,is any other solution to add header (image with text) onn every page